# How to programmatically determine a Cocoa plugin bundle's garbage collection settings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, garbage-collection

On Mac OS X using Objective-C 2, plugin bundles can be compiled with one of three garbage collection settings:

1. Not Supported
2. Supported (`-fobjc-gc`)
3. Required (`-fobjc-gc-only`)

How can one programmatically query a compiled plugin bundle to determine which of these three settings was used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the answer from [diciu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2811/diciu), you can use the [Mach-O API](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html). You have to parse the segments contained in the binary file and search for the **__OBJC** one; the `segment_command` structure allows an access to the segment's flags.

You can also take a look at the [ClassDump project](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/). It has a pretty complete Mach-O parser.

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the __OBJC segment but I don't know of any API that exposes it.

Garbage collected:

```
cristi:tmp diciu$ otool -v -o ./a.out 
./a.out:
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_classrefs) section
00000001000010b0 0x0
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_imageinfo) section
  version 0
    flags 0x6 OBJC_IMAGE_SUPPORTS_GC
```

Non garbage collected:

```
cristi:tmp diciu$ otool -v -o ./a.out 
./a.out:
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_classrefs) section
00000001000010b0 0x0
Contents of (__DATA,__objc_imageinfo) section
  version 0
    flags 0x0
```

The runtime does this using private functions: [see *gc_enforcer* and it's use of * _objcInfoRequiresGC*](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-371/runtime/objc-runtime.m)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to just try and load the bundle using NSBundle's `-loadAndReturnError:` method. If the bundle won't load due to the fact that its GC settings are different to those in your app, you'll get an `NSExecutableRuntimeMismatchError`.